# Redirect a page at specific instant

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How do I redirect to a page at a specific time?

Say wish to redirect on `31st dec 12:00AM`, and people visiting after `12:00` must get directly redirected to new site.

Is this possible in `jquery` or `PHP`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: you can use javascript

Comment: now days it is a common question,can you do my homework?

Comment: pseudo code: `if (current_time > 'dec 31 12am') { redirect to new page }`

Comment: Do you need to redirect people already on the site, or just when they visit a page? That will determine if the code needs to be client-side and/or server-side only. *Best provide details fast, before this question gets closed as off-topic!* :)

Comment: if some one is on the site he should be redirected to new page, if he/she visits after that particular time, they should directly go to next page.

Comment: i tried taking time stamp of a particular datetime and directly comparing with now, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP code will check before the page is loaded, so new visitors will be redirected, and the javascript code will check every 10 seconds after the page is loaded, so existing visitors will be redirected.

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime("December 31st, 2014 12:00AM");
    $now = time();

    if($now > $date->getTimestamp()) // if it's past the date
    {
        header("Location: http://google.com/");
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkDate()
            {
                // Year: 2014
                // Month: 11 is December (0-11)
                // Day: 31st
                var date = new Date(2014, 11, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                var now = new Date();

                if(now > date) // if it's past the date
                {
                    window.location.replace("http://google.com/");
                }
            }          

            $(function() {
                window.setInterval(checkDate, 10 * 1000); // check every ten seconds
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe js method is appropriate, but presently its not working.

Comment: works if you pass parameters in this manner : 
var date = new Date("May 28,2014,22:17:00");

Comment: @SiddharthPatel The code does exactly what you asked for, which is absolutely nothing unless it's after December 31st 2014

Comment: I understand that,i tried editing it with present date, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in Javascript and PHP.

This will redirect in JS:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");
```

This will redirect in PHP:

```
<?php
   header("Location: http://www.example.com");
?>
```

Whichever you go with you'll just need to put it in an if statement to check if the condition for the redirect is correct.

Javascript will require a timer as well if you want it to redirect when you get to the specific time instead of only checking on first load.